# teradata hadoop connector to pull data from teradata

Tags: hadoop, teradata

Is there any Teradata hadoop connector available? I know of jdbc connector which can be used in sqoop, but apart from that is there any other connector available (ODBC or anything else)

A small example would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Teradata connector for hadoop @ [teradata](https://developer.teradata.com/connectivity/articles/teradata-connector-for-hadoop-now-available)

Have a look at this [Tutorial](https://developer.teradata.com/sites/all/files/Teradata%20Connector%20for%20Hadoop%20Tutorial%20v1%200%20final.pdf) for better understanding & resolving issues during development.

Comment: A small point => I can see a discrepancy b/w the document (the link you provided) and `https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.db2biga.doc/doc/biga_load_from.html?lang=en`. In the bigsql document it is saying PARQUET file format is also supported, but the link you provided not telling anything about PARQUET.

Comment: I did not get sufficient evidence on PARQUET support from connector end.